# Google maps on Android just stopped working

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I had working code showing my location on a nice little google map. with out changing any map code suddenly the map is completely blank  (a grey grey square) thats it..

using google map api for android v2.  all set up with an api key and everything.. it was working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen for a few reasons. Did you sign this version of the application with a different certificate? Are you sure your device has an internet connection? You can also check the logs as Google Maps usually spams a bunch of information about why it is unable to connect. I run into this issue sometimes when my phone is running internet through a proxy, you might want to check that as well.

Comment: how would i know if its going through a proxy... the api signature is a whole other problem.. sometimes it says failure to connect to the google api and that the api key may be wrong.. if i back out of the activity and come back that error goes away and thats when i see a grey square instead of an actual map.. its really frustrating

Comment: You would have had to set it to go through a proxy, if you didn't I don't think that is the problem. I would double check your key signature and make sure you have that set on you google code project.

Comment: as it turns out, it was a memory issue.  I was loading a cameraPreview Surface View as well as a GoogleMap.  The solution was to set the cameraPreview to INVISBLE immediately after initiating it.. then do the map then set the camera to visible again..